# How does SqlAlchemy handle unique constraint in table definition

Tags: sqlalchemy, unique

I have a table with the following declarative definition:

```
class Type(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Type'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique = True)
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

The column "name" has a unique constraint, but I'm able to do

```
type1 = Type('name1')
session.add(type1)
type2 = Type(type1.name)
session.add(type2)
```

So, as can be seen, the unique constraint is not checked at all, since I have added to the session 2 objects with the same name.

When I do `session.commit()`, I get a mysql error since the constraint is also in the mysql table.

Is it possible that sqlalchemy tells me in advance that I can not make it or identifies it and does not insert 2 entries with the same "name" columm?
If not, should I keep in memory all existing names, so I can check if they exist of not, before creating the object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SQLAlechemy doesn't handle uniquness, because it's not possible to do good way. Even if you keep track of created objects and/or check whether object with such name exists there is a race condition: anybody in other process can insert a new object with the name you just checked. The only solution is to lock whole table before check and release the lock after insertion (some databases support such locking).

Comment: I'll be the only one inserting data there, so I'll make sure this does not happen. My question is specifically about how sqlalchemy handles uniqueness of a field

Comment: @duduklein It doesn't handle uniqueness. And my answer describes why.

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK, sqlalchemy does not handle uniqueness constraints in python behavior. Those "unique=True" declarations are only used to impose database level table constraints, and only then if you create the table using a sqlalchemy command, i.e.

```
Type.__table__.create(engine)
```

or some such. If you create an SA model against an existing table that does not actually have this constraint present, it will be as if it does not exist.

Depending on your specific use case, you'll probably have to use a pattern like

```
try:
  existing = session.query(Type).filter_by(name='name1').one()
  # do something with existing
except:
  newobj = Type('name1')
  session.add(newobj)
```

or a variant, or you'll just have to catch the mysql exception and recover from there.

Answer (score 2):

[From the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html#table-configuration)

```
class MyClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sometable'
    __table_args__ = (
            ForeignKeyConstraint(['id'], ['remote_table.id']),
            UniqueConstraint('foo'),
            {'autoload':True}
            )
```

Comment: What's the different between this and using `unique=True` as presented in the original question?

Comment: `unique=True` does not afford the opportunity to specify a unique name for the index, which will cause problems with alembic. See: https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/naming.html

Comment: Okay, but does this answer the original question? I think some more explanation of your relation to the OP's question could be helpful.

Comment: Not sure, but this question is almost a decade old now, and this isn't the accepted answer.

Comment: that doesn't mean it isn't still discovered often. I'm just trying to understand your answer and explain my -1.

Comment: Appreciate that you're trying to learn! Do you have any questions or is there something specific you're looking to understand about sqlalchemy that I could help you with? I've spent the past 8 years since I answered this question (poorly?) getting better at sqlalchemy! So I'd be glad to help you out in any way I can

Answer (score 1):

`.one()` throws two kinds of exceptions:
`sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound` and `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.MultipleResultsFound`

You should create that object when the first exception occurs, if the second occurs you're screwed anyway and shouldn't make is worse.

```
try:
  existing = session.query(Type).filter_by(name='name1').one()
# do something with existing
except NoResultFound:
  newobj = Type('name1')
  session.add(newobj)
```